# Common SQL to compare dates in SQL Server and ORACLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need to include a date comparison in my query where I compare a date string to a `DATETIME` column but i need it to work on both ORACLE and SQL Server and not have two separate queries.
Are there any date comparissons which will work on both oracle and sql?

ORACLE:

```
Select * from MyTable where myDate > DATE '2013-04-10'
```

SQL Server:

```
Select * from MyTable where myDate > convert(DATETIME,'2013-04-10', 126)
```

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand No the above doesnt work in oracle. It errors saying its an invalid month.

Comment: @CathalMF that [depends on your NLS settings](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9820) as mentioned by Ed.

Comment: @JackDouglas - you're correct; I overstated the point there. I should have said "messy" or "risky" and left it at that. I'll edit the comment.

Comment: Well, for some reason I can't edit the comment so hopefully any future readers will make their way down the comments.

Comment: @EdGibbs have you heard of [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)? I'm pretty sure you'd find the odd question there to your liking, we have a pretty [broad definition of 'DBA'](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq), and I can tell you know a lot about Oracle.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the delete/re-post advice; shoulda thought of that! Here goes: in Oracle, any string dates are parsed using the NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting, which is usually 'DD-MON-RR' (2-digit day #, month name abbreviation, 2-digit year with century rollup), so WHERE myDate > '20130410' will throw `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`. You can get away with it if you do `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD', but that can get messy.

Comment: @JackDouglas - Thanks for the dba.se link - very interesting stuff there! And you're too kind - I'm really more of a query savant in Oracle, with very little in the way of hardcore DBA-type skills, so the "broad definition of DBA" is comforting :) I can tell I'll learn a lot by lurking there, so again - thanks!

Comment: @EdGibbs dba.SE is as much about advanced querying, syntax and performance tuning as it is about traditional DBA tasks like backups, configuration, etc.

Comment: The standards support of Microsoft SQL Server is this area is non-existant. No ANSI date literals, no INTERVAL and no CURRENT_DATE.

Answer (score 5):

This portability issue only applies with literals.

I do not believe there is a fully portable way to do this because SQL Server does not support the ANSI literal DATE keyword and all the CAST, CONVERT, TO_DATE, and date functions are not identical on all platforms.

Note that your second query can also be written as `Select * from MyTable where myDate > '20130410'`.

It would be nice if there was support in SQL Server for the ANSI DATE literal feature (DB/2 and Teradata both have this).

I could not find a Connect item on this, nor anything about why SQL Server doesn't support the ANSI DATE, TIME and TIMESTAMP literal keywords.

I'm wondering in your scenario, whether it would be possible to use a parameter instead?

The solution in Jack's comment [Common SQL to compare dates in SQL Server and ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040117/common-sql-to-compare-dates-in-sql-server-and-oracle#comment22889738_16040483) will make this code portable, but you will have to have a non-portable scalar function.  This might be a viable option for you - note that in SQL Server, you will need to prefix a scalar function with its schema - this might introduce another wrinkle between the Oracle code and SQL code if you can't make the schemas the same name (note in Oracle, the prefix could be the name of a package instead of a schema if you put the function inside a package)

Answer (score 1):

Is defining your own user-defined functions allowed?  You could create a function which abstracts the DBMS specific code and returns a literal 'True' or 'False' result.

[MSSQL User Defined Functions: ]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms186755.aspx

[Oracle User Defined Functions]http://ocs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200

Oracle apparently does not allow user defined functions to return a Boolean type, so a string (or numeric) result is required.

Comment: why not just create a function that takes a string and returns a date?

Comment: Because he's asking for a test to apply to a row.

Comment: `select * from MyTable where myDate > give_me_the_date('2013-04-10')`